# Upgrade Hibernate 3.6 to hibernate 4.3.6 on jboss 6.0.0 AS getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/classic/Session

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jboss

We are upgrading **hibernate 3.6** to **hibernate 4.3.6** in our application and we are using **hibernate JPA 2.0** in **Jboss 6.0.0**. We have excluded jpa components and other JBoss components and bundled our own libs (i.e jpa hibernate etc) after deploying  and starting the Jboss.

**We get :**

```
17:50:31,788 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Real: name=vfs:///C:/Jboss/jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/XXXXXX/deploy/XXXXXX-6.4.1.ear state=PreReal mode=Manual requiredState=Real: org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error deploying XXXXXXEJB3.jar: org/hibernate/classic/Session
at org.jboss.ejb3.deployers.Ejb3Deployer.deploy(Ejb3Deployer.java:194) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.ejb3.deployers.Ejb3Deployer.deploy(Ejb3Deployer.java:60) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.AbstractSimpleVFSRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractSimpleVFSRealDeployer.java:56) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:55) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1832) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1550) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1603) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1491) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.change(DeployersImpl.java:1983) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:1076) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:679) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.process(MainDeployerPlugin.java:106) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.process(ProfileControllerContext.java:143) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.deploy(ProfileDeployAction.java:151) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.installActionInternal(ProfileDeployAction.java:94) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper$BasicProfileActivation.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:190) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:87) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activateProfile(ProfileActivationService.java:215) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activate(ProfileActivationService.java:159) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.activate(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:112) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.resolver.BasicResolverFactory$ProfileResolverFacade.deploy(BasicResolverFactory.java:87) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.start(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:91) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:132) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:56) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer.startBootstraps(AbstractServer.java:827) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-5]
at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer$StartServerTask.run(AbstractServer.java:417) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-5]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_31]
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/classic/Session
at org.jboss.injection.PcEncInjector.<clinit>(PcEncInjector.java:48) [:1.7.17]
at org.jboss.injection.PersistenceContextHandler.loadXml(PersistenceContextHandler.java:73) [:1.7.17]
at org.jboss.ejb3.EJBContainer.processMetadata(EJBContainer.java:779) [:1.7.17]
at org.jboss.ejb3.Ejb3Deployment.processEJBContainerMetadata(Ejb3Deployment.java:471) [:1.7.17]
at org.jboss.ejb3.Ejb3Deployment.create(Ejb3Deployment.java:553) [:1.7.17]
at org.jboss.ejb3.deployers.Ejb3Deployer.deploy(Ejb3Deployer.java:177) [:6.0.0.Final]
... 49 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.classic.Session from BaseClassLoader@5b3ba312{vfs:///C:/Jboss/jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/XXXXXX/conf/jboss-service.xml}
at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:480) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_31]
... 55 more
```

Removed all the reference somewhere jboss bootstrap class loader looks for org/hibernate/classic/Session We couldn't find the reference . Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the JBoss 6.0 EJB3 implementation is dependent upon the version of Hibernate that you have removed.

Why don't you upgrade to JBossAS 7.x for JPA 2.0 support?

Comment: Is there any reference link that i can see Jboss6 Ejb3.1 implementation depends on hibernate3.6, I have searched all the links i can't find. Since it is legacy swing application in support only we have no time on upgrade.